# Why can I pull one string out of an NSDictionary, but not another?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary and I am trying to pull a string out of it. For some reason, the last string seems irretrievable(!?!). In the code below, I retrieve the NSString object for labelString, with no problem at all. But when I try to retrieve the NSString for foo, I always get nil. But I don't see the difference - can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:CellStyleLabelledStringCell], @"cellStyle",
                      @"name", @"fieldName", 
                      @"Name", @"labelString", 
                      foodItem.name, @"contentString", 
                      @"foo", @"fookey",
                      nil];

NSString *string1 = (NSString *)[dict objectForKey:@"fookey"];
NSString *string2 = (NSString *)[dict objectForKey:@"labelString"];
NSLog(@"[%@][%@]", string1, string2);
```

The log message looks like this, and backs-up what I'm seeing in the debugger (i.e., string1 is null):

2012-03-17 21:35:03.302 QuickList7[8244:fb03] [(null)][Name]

Truly perplexed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foodItem.name` is nil, so `-[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]` stops there, and doesn't add the subsequent objects to the dictionary.

In other words, it's as if you did this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:CellStyleLabelledStringCell], @"cellStyle",
                      @"name", @"fieldName", 
                      @"Name", @"labelString", 
                      nil];
```

This is why you have to be careful with any method that takes `nil` as an "end of arguments" sentinel.

Answer (score 1):

Kurt's answer is correct, foodItem.name is nil.

To prevent that, you can either always check objects to see if they're nil before adding to a dictionary, or use the following macro to replace all nil items with NSNull objects:

`#define n2N(value) (value ? value : [NSNull null])`

So using that macro, your code above would look like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  [NSNumber numberWithInt:CellStyleLabelledStringCell], @"cellStyle",
                  @"name", @"fieldName", 
                  @"Name", @"labelString", 
                  n2N(foodItem.name), @"contentString", 
                  @"foo", @"fookey",
                  nil];
```

---

Also, there's no need to typecast the result of `objectForKey:` to `NSString` since that method returns id.

Comment: I like the macro idea, that's slick. Thanks!